# matplotlib | Plot value above bars

Tags: python, for-loop, matplotlib, printf, bioinformatics

I have values that I want to plot above each of the two bars.

I'm sure it's dead easy but I cannot get my `# Values` for loop to work for the life of me.

```
    for i, v in enumerate(y):
        plt.text(i, v, str(v) + "\n", ha='center', va='bottom')
        #plt.text(i, v, str(v))
        #plt.text(float(y[i]), v, str(v))
```

Comment: `plt.text(i, v, str(v))`?  Note that `v` and `y[i]` are the same here.

Comment: @JohanC. This now displays text ! How do I get it to be more balanced?

Comment: for example `plt.text(i, v, str(v)+"\n", ha='center', va='bottom')`

Comment: Thank you v much man :) @JohanC

Comment: @JohanC How could I make to values above the chart print to 2 dp w/ %? I tried 'str(round(v,2) + "%)"' but with no luck. Even without 'str()' and '%' it doesn't work

Comment: Maybe use an f-string:  f`\n{v:.2f}%`?

Comment: @JohanC Got it working with your solution. Cheers man. Your help has taught me more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
for i,v in enumerate(y):
   plt.text(i,v,v)
```